# Ipython directive creates corrupted output during building docs

Tags: python, datatable, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-sphinx

I want to build docs using sphinx and ipython directive.
I try on simple command in .rst document:

```
.. ipython:: python

    import datatable as dt
    DT = dt.Frame(A=range(5))
    DT
```

In jupyter notebook results look well:

[image]

but during building make html results corrupted:

[image]

what could be the reason?

It works well with pandas or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue in ipython here is a link to issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11424

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the needed extensions in your `conf.py`:

```
extensions = ['IPython.sphinxext.ipython_console_highlighting',
              'IPython.sphinxext.ipython_directive']
```